# Русский текст в консольных приложениях на C++

Tags: windows, c++

Вот например я пишу

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "я программко";
    return 0;
}
```

но он выводит мне не "я программко", а какой-то `№;%:?*:%;№"№;%:?*`.
Почему это и как с этим бороться?

Comment: классика жанра от Michael S. Kaplan: [CONVENTIONAL WISDOM IS RETARDED, AKA WHAT THE @#%&* IS _O_U16TEXT?](http://www.siao2.com/2008/03/18/8306597.aspx)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

char* rus(const char* text) 
{
    char *buffRus=new char[strlen(text)];
    CharToOem(text, buffRus);
    return buffRus;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout<<rus("Привет")<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: По пальцам бить за такое =)<br />Хотя вспоминаю время обучения, так нам вообще какой-то russian.h давали, который наверно это и делал... Печально...

Comment: что означает звезда перед именем функции? это вроде ссылку на что-то означает, но как может функция хранить в себе ссылку на что-то???извините, я еще совсем чайник))

Comment: To @"Илья Михневич" char * означает, что функция rus() возвращает адрес строки, которую она создает выполняя оператор new.

Comment: в почему не char *rus??? или разницы нет??
то есть, если я правильно понял, то return buffRus возвращает не ее значение, а ссылку на нее?

Comment: "в почему не char *rus???"
без разницы где пробел ставить.

Comment: "то return buffRus возвращает не ее значение, а ссылку на нее?"
buffRus - это указатель. Т.е. это переменная, хранящая в себе некий адрес памяти. char* - это указатель на переменную типа char. Разные типы указателей сделаны, чтобы Вы случайно не могли их смешать и перепутать.

new char[strlen(text)]; - создает в памяти место под строчку длиной strlen(text) символов и возвращает указатель на начало этой памяти.
CharToOem(text, buffRus); - берет строчку text, преобразует и кладет в память, начиная с адреса buffRus.
Итого - buffRus теперь указывает на строчку в уже правильной кодировке.

Answer (score 12):

Используйте setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"Russian");

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
setlocale(LC_CTYPE,"Russian");
cout << "я программко";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Не обязательно первый параметр писать именно таким. Я, например, обычно пишу  setlocale(NULL,"Russian");.

Comment: В большинстве случаев и так можно setlocale(0, "");

Comment: спасибо, учту)))

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю программу писать не с устаревшими однобайтными кодировками, а в Unicode. Т.е. используйте wchar и производные. Для создания unicode литерала используйте макрос _T() или литерал L.
Пример:

```
L"this is a literal string"
_T("Hello")
```

PS: для вывода в юникоде есть wcout:

```
std::wcout<<L"TestString"<<std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

В окне командной строки ОБЫЧНО кодировка CP866. Ее можно изменить на CP1251, стандартную для остальной части Windows командой chcp 1251, но ни к чему хорошему это не приводит. Вообще, две кодировки в винде - это очень неудобно.

Хорошая программа командной строки должна по умолчанию выводить текст в файл (например при переназначении потока вывода) в кодировке CP1251, а на терминал в CP866. Надо определить (например вызвав isatty()) куда направлен вывод и делать соответствующую перекодировку из кодировки строк в программе.

На самом деле, надо еще анализировать LANG (или что-то аналогичное в винде) и выводить сообщения на нужном ЯЗЫКЕ (ну и конечно, в правильной кодировке).

Comment: А писать сразу в Unicode не поможет?

Comment: Лучше utf-8. Хотя если честно то тем же грешат и sysinternals. Я постоянно из них треш из букв получаю при ошибках удаленного запуска.

Comment: А кто переведет Unicode или UTF-8 в кодировку консоли ? Сам, ну может для C++ есть какой нибудь метод какого нибудь класса для расширения потока вывода, не знаю, в плюсах не силен.

Comment: Ну, не знаю, у меня консоль юникодовская и проблем не возникает. Или вероятно сам виндовз или CRT догадывается, что нужно сделать преобразование.

Comment: Ага, US и консоль Unicode, и в файлах UTF-8 лежит (а в начале половины из них 3 байта сигнатуры - ха-ха-ха). Это снимает много проблем. Но у нас обычно русская Винда, у нее по другому. Кстати, а как понять (из C программы) как Винда настроена ?

Comment: "Но у нас обычно русская Винда, у нее по другому" - по жизни ставлю Eng с пакетом MUI Rus, иначе фуфло получается. Это для клиентов. Для себя - Eng без MUI, т.к. предпочитаю пользоваться оригинальной. А перевод на русский просто нелеп.

Comment: "Кстати, а как понять (из C программы) как Винда настроена ?" - стандартными средствами языка, боюсь, никак. Если искать какие-то библиотеки - почему нет, но зачем?

Answer (score 1):

Потом при запуске проги клацни правой кнопкой на **строку заголовка**(верхняя строка окна, в которой находится имя программы или имя окна)**->Cвойства->Шрифт->Lucida Console**.И все будет работать!!

```
#include <iostream>
    using namespace std;
    int main(){
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
        cout << "я программко";
        return 0;
```

Comment: Кстати спасибо Администрации что забанили...

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в компиляторе. Он компилирует строки в неправильной кодировке. Стандартная кодировка для командной строки CP866. Вот где поправить это я к сожалению не подскажу.

Answer (score 0):

`CharToOem` сработало.
`SetConsole` -- НЕТ :-(

To Андрей Кузьменко -- прежде,  чем бить по пальцам -- ВЫУЧИТЕ МАТЧАСТЬ.
`russian.h` не нужен. `*` означает указатель на тип. Мне код понравился. 
И не вынуждайте меня объяснять Вам разницу между `*`, `&` и `&*`.

```
char * func (int a, char * , float &* )
```

-- так вот :-)

Comment: @DragonLeo, по поводу SetConsole. Вы просто не переключили шрифт в консоли (**Cвойства->Шрифт->Lucida Console**). 

Если переключить, то после     SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251); вывод будет русскими буквами (в cp1251).

Answer (score -1):

```
// ConsoleApplication4.cpp: главный файл проекта.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <conio.h>

using namespace System;

int main()
{
    Console::WriteLine(L"Здравствуй, мир!");
    _getch();
}
```

Comment: Представьте себе, это не C++.