# Как добавить русский язык в C++ Builder?

Tags: c++builder, ide

Собственно не могу понять, как сделать в консоли русский язык в данной программе. Вместо русских букв появляются крякозябры.

Comment: Попробуйте поменять настройки консоли, возможно стандартный шрифт не поддерживает русский язык

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос хорошо разобран [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/12334/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c).