# Непонятные знаки в консоли вместо русских букв

Tags: кодировка, c++

При отладке примера консольного приложения в консоли вместо русских букв появляются непонятные знаки. Вместо Апельсины не единственные фрукты, и всего у нас, фруктов при отладке в консоли получается неправильная кодировка. Как это исправить?

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    int apples, orange;
    int fruit;
    apples = 5;
    orange = 6;
    fruit = apples + orange;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Апельсины не единственные фрукты......" << endl << "- и всего у нас " << fruit << " фруктов.";
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Как же вы достали с этим вопросом, вот честно, до глубины души...

Comment: Вообще @Vezd заслуживает большего. Поскольку фраза "Апельсины не единственные фрукты" для обозначения подобных вопросов мне кажется весьма подходящей

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Раз.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/12334/windows-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c)

[Два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/117144/%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c)

А в гугле так вообще не счесть.

Comment: Да и на ХэшКоде было много ответов (и получше этих 2-х). Но как их быстро найти?