# Как определить, есть ли буквы в строке? C++

Tags: c++

Как определить, есть ли буквы в строке без функций и очень коротко. (буквы любые - и латинские, и русские)

Comment: Создаёте Set букв(ну или `isalpha/iswalpha`), идёте по строке, нашли букву - вернули true.

Comment: «любые» — это только латинские и русские или все остальные языки тоже? Иероглифы считаются буквами?

Comment: что вы рассматриваете буквой  `isalpha()`? `\p{L}`? К примеру, что является буквой в `u8"\u0435\u0308"` строке?

Comment: связанный вопрос [C++ How to check if letter isalpha (not latin alphabet)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28282357/4279)

Comment: Недостаточно информации, чтобы дать полный ответ. Напишите пожалуйста, для каких языков нужно определять буквы - только латинские и русские или могут быть любые? Если только латинские и русские - то в какой кодировке? Если любые - то в какой кодировке?

Comment: Что значит без функций? Может сразу и на циклы ограничение добавить? И на условные переходы заодно.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28282357/c-how-to-check-if-letter-isalpha-not-latin-alphabet

Answer (score 2):

Если хочется без функций, то можно очень просто

```
std::string s = "stroka"; // наша строка
for (int i = 0; i< s.length(); i++) { // идем по символам
  if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z' || s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z') 
     std::cout << "found!" << std::endl;
     break;
  }
}
```

в коде явно прописан break, так как в задании написно "есть ли буквы". Если хотя бы одну нашли, дальше нет смысла продолжать.

С кириллицей немного сложнее - тут все зависит от кодировок. Так как обычно такие задачи задают для винды, приложение запускают с консоли (которая имеет кодировку 866), а сам код набирают либо в cp1251б либо в utf-8/utf-16, то тут проблема. Поэтому простое решение вида

```
if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z' || s[i] >= 'a' && s[i] <= 'z' ||
s[i] >= 'А' && s[i] <= 'Я' || s[i] >= 'а' && s[i] <= 'я' || 
s[i] == 'Ё' || s[i] == 'ё')
```

вряд ли сработает так просто. Но возможно, после прочтения [поста](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/12334/%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c) все и заработает. Да, и буква Ё хитрая, она в cp1251 находиться отдельно. Поєтому и обрабатывается отдельно.

Можно ли данный код написать короче и при этом без функций? можно, но он станет запутанней и вряд ли понравиться преподавателю (задание очень на это похоже).

Кстати, `length()` - это вообще то функция, но думаю, на нее условие не распространяется.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, если вы работаете с кириллицей на C++, вам необходимо перейти на широкие строки (`wstring`), у узких строк масса проблем.

Далее, чтобы не думать о том, где какие символы расположены, проще всего задать список букв вручную один раз.

Получаем:

```
std::wstring letters =
        L"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        L"абвгдеёжщийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюяАБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
```

Имея список букв, проверка тривиальна:

```
s.find_first_of(letters) != std::wstring::npos
```

Это один вызов функции. Меньше вызовов функции реально использовать не выйдет, т. к. индексация и опрос размера строк — тоже вызовы функций. Но можно притвориться, что вызовов функций нет в таком коде:

```
for (auto c : s)
    for (auto c1 : letters)
        if (c == c1)
            return true;
return false;
```

(хотя в реальности тут под капотом вызываются функции получения итераторов и их инкремента).

Comment: Ради интереса, какие плюсы у широких строк в противовес узким? (при работе с кириллицей)

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Смотрите. У нас есть два вида узких строк: ANSI (то есть, однобайтная кодировка), и UTF-8. У ANSI-кодировок проблемы такие. Во-первых, их сложно вводить с консоли. ([Большой ответ по теме.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/459299/10105)) Затем, у них проблемы с несоответствием кодовой страницы редактора, компилятора и консоли — введённый текст с точки зрения рантайма может оказаться не тем, чем его считает пользователь. И затем, в однобайтной кодировке нельзя представить даже полный английский с надстрочными элементами (Beyoncé, tête-à-tête, née).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Теперь UTF-8. С ним проблем ещё больше. Во-первых, под винду он очень слабо поддерживается, это серьёзная проблема. Затем, как вы будете искать символ в строке? UTF-8 — многобайтная кодировка, поэтому вам придётся вместо символа искать **подстроку**, т. к. кириллица кодируется уже несколькими символами. Вы не можете для UTF-8-строки использовать индексацию даже в простых случаях. У UTF-16-строки с индексами проблема появляется лишь в случае наличия суррогатных пар, а для поиска можно использовать сравнение с символом (`wchar_t`) без проблем.

Comment: Согласен, спасибо за подробное объяснение.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

Будет искать только латинские

```
std::string str = "0 - это цифра, O - это буква"; 
bool est = false; 
for ( int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++ ) {
  if ( ( ( str[i] >= 'A' ) && ( str[i] <= 'Z' ) ) 
        || ( ( str[i] >= 'a' ) && ( str[i] <= 'z' ) ) 
     ) { 
    est = true; 
    break;
}
```

est или не est вот в чем ответ. Сработает на букву 'O'.

Чтобы работало со строками UTF-8 и т.п. (то есть чтобы поддерживало русский и другие языки) так просто уже не получится, придется использовать функции библиотек.

Comment: Ух как вы обидели кучу других языков и букву ё

Comment: а код не будет компилироваться:)

Comment: теперь будет, и Ё :-)